# Why audio doesn't play on the packaged electronJS app?

Tags: electron, electron-builder

I have an electronJS app that plays an mp3 audio on certain events. The audio is played well if I run the electron app with `yarn dev` or `yarn start`. But when I package the electron app and test out the packaged app on release folder, the audio is not played. What is the problem here?

My dev, start, and package scripts can be seen on package.json below:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "build": "concurrently \"yarn build-main\" \"yarn build-renderer\"",
    "build-dll": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.dll.babel.js --colors",
    "build-e2e": "cross-env E2E_BUILD=true yarn build",
    "build-main": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.main.prod.babel.js --colors",
    "build-renderer": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack --config ./configs/webpack.config.renderer.prod.babel.js --colors",
    "dev": "cross-env START_HOT=1 node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckPortInUse.js && cross-env START_HOT=1 yarn start-renderer-dev",
    "flow": "flow",
    "flow-typed": "rimraf flow-typed/npm && flow-typed install --overwrite || true",
    "lint": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development eslint --cache --format=pretty .",
    "lint-fix": "yarn --silent lint --fix; exit 0",
    "lint-styles": "stylelint --ignore-path .eslintignore '**/*.*(css|scss)' --syntax scss",
    "lint-styles-fix": "yarn --silent lint-styles --fix; exit 0",
    "package": "yarn build && electron-builder build --publish never",
    "package-all": "yarn build && electron-builder build -mwl",
    "package-ci": "yarn postinstall && yarn build && electron-builder --publish always",
    "package-linux": "yarn build && electron-builder build --linux",
    "package-win": "yarn build && electron-builder build --win --x64",
    "postinstall": "yarn flow-typed && electron-builder install-app-deps package.json && yarn build-dll && opencollective-postinstall",
    "postlint-fix": "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write '**/*.{*{js,jsx,json},babelrc,eslintrc,prettierrc,stylelintrc}'",
    "postlint-styles-fix": "prettier --ignore-path .eslintignore --single-quote --write '**/*.{css,scss}'",
    "prestart": "yarn build",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production electron ./app/main.prod.js",
    "start-main-dev": "cross-env HOT=1 NODE_ENV=development electron -r @babel/register ./app/main.dev.js",
    "start-renderer-dev": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development webpack-dev-server --config configs/webpack.config.renderer.dev.babel.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test BABEL_DISABLE_CACHE=1 jest",
    "test-all": "yarn lint && yarn flow && yarn build && yarn test && yarn build-e2e && yarn test-e2e",
    "test-e2e": "node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe electron:./ ./test/e2e/HomePage.e2e.js",
    "test-e2e-live": "node -r @babel/register ./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js && cross-env NODE_ENV=test testcafe-live electron:./ ./test/e2e/HomePage.e2e.js",
    "test-watch": "yarn test --watch"
  },
  "main": "./app/main.prod.js",
  "build": {
    "productName": "Timy",
    "appId": "org.forstek.timy",
    "files": [
      "app/dist/",
      "app/app.html",
      "app/main.prod.js",
      "app/main.prod.js.map",
      "package.json"
    ],
    "dmg": {
      "contents": [
        {
          "x": 130,
          "y": 220
        },
        {
          "x": 410,
          "y": 220,
          "type": "link",
          "path": "/Applications"
        }
      ]
    },
    "win": {
      "target": [
        "nsis",
        "msi"
      ]
    },
    "linux": {
      "target": [
        "deb",
        "rpm",
        "snap",
        "AppImage"
      ],
      "category": "Development"
    },
    "directories": {
      "buildResources": "resources",
      "output": "release"
    },
    "publish": {
      "provider": "github",
      "owner": "forstek",
      "repo": "timy",
      "private": false
    }
  },
  "keywords": [
    "electron",
    "boilerplate",
    "react",
    "redux",
    "flow",
    "sass",
    "webpack",
    "hot",
    "reload"
  ],
  "homepage": ".",
  "jest": {
    "testURL": "http://localhost/",
    "moduleNameMapper": {
      "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|eot|otf|webp|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|mp4|webm|wav|mp3|m4a|aac|oga)$": "<rootDir>/internals/mocks/fileMock.js",
      "\\.(css|less|sass|scss)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
    "moduleFileExtensions": [
      "js",
      "jsx",
      "json"
    ],
    "transform": {
      "^.+\\.jsx?$": "babel-jest"
    },
    "setupFiles": [
      "./internals/scripts/CheckBuiltsExist.js"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-do-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-default-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-export-namespace-from": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-bind": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-function-sent": "^7.1.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-json-strings": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-logical-assignment-operators": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-nullish-coalescing-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-numeric-separator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-pipeline-operator": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-throw-expressions": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-dynamic-import": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-syntax-import-meta": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.1.6",
    "@babel/preset-flow": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.0.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.0.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^23.6.0",
    "babel-loader": "^8.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-dev-expression": "^0.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.4.20",
    "chalk": "^2.4.1",
    "concurrently": "^4.1.0",
    "connected-react-router": "^5.0.1",
    "cross-env": "^5.2.0",
    "cross-spawn": "^6.0.5",
    "css-loader": "^1.0.1",
    "dayjs": "^1.10.7",
    "detect-port": "^1.3.0",
    "electron": "^3.0.10",
    "electron-builder": "21.2.0",
    "electron-devtools-installer": "3.2.0",
    "enzyme": "^3.7.0",
    "enzyme-adapter-react-16": "^1.7.0",
    "enzyme-to-json": "^3.3.4",
    "eslint": "^5.9.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-formatter-pretty": "^2.0.0",
    "eslint-import-resolver-webpack": "^0.10.1",
    "eslint-plugin-compat": "^2.6.3",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^3.2.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jest": "^22.0.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "6.1.2",
    "eslint-plugin-promise": "^4.0.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-testcafe": "^0.2.1",
    "fbjs-scripts": "^1.0.1",
    "file-loader": "^2.0.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.77.0",
    "flow-runtime": "^0.17.0",
    "flow-typed": "^2.5.1",
    "husky": "^1.1.4",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "^23.6.0",
    "lint-staged": "^8.1.0",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^0.4.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.10.0",
    "opencollective-postinstall": "^2.0.1",
    "optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin": "^5.0.1",
    "prettier": "^1.15.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "^16.6.3",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "rimraf": "^2.6.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "sinon": "^7.1.1",
    "spectron": "^5.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.23.1",
    "stylelint": "^9.8.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^4.0.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^18.2.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "^1.1.0",
    "testcafe": "^0.23.2",
    "testcafe-browser-provider-electron": "^0.0.6",
    "testcafe-live": "^0.1.4",
    "testcafe-react-selectors": "^3.0.0",
    "url-loader": "^1.1.2",
    "webpack": "^4.26.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^3.0.3",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.1.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^3.1.10",
    "webpack-merge": "^4.1.4",
    "yarn": "^1.12.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.5.0",
    "@getstation/electron-google-oauth2": "2.1.0",
    "antd": "^4.16.2",
    "axios": "0.21.1",
    "crypto-js": "^4.0.0",
    "devtron": "^1.4.0",
    "electron-debug": "^2.0.0",
    "electron-log": "^2.2.17",
    "electron-updater": "4.0.0",
    "history": "^4.7.2",
    "js-cookie": "^2.2.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "2.29.1",
    "moment-duration-format": "2.3.2",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-hot-loader": "^4.3.12",
    "react-icons": "4.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.1.1",
    "react-router": "^4.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.3.1",
    "recompose": "0.30.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.1",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "source-map-support": "^0.5.9",
    "styled-components": "5.3.0",
    "validator": "^13.6.0"
  },
  "devEngines": {
    "node": ">=7.x",
    "npm": ">=4.x",
    "yarn": ">=0.21.3"
  },
  "browserslist": "electron 1.6"
}
```

The electron version where I get this problem is 3.0.10. Electron-builder version is 21.2.0.

The audio file is located on `/app/assets/audio/notif.mp3`

Do I need to put also this file on `/resources` folder?

Comment: Electron v3.0.10 is very old. Try updating Electron and re-run. As of the 14th March 2022, the latest Electron release is v17.1.1  See [Stable Releases](https://www.electronjs.org/releases/stable)

Comment: Without seeing more of your project, we are not able to help. If you post your package.json (especially the "files" and "extraFiles" properties), as well as where your mp3 audio files are, that should help.

Comment: @reZach I have updated the question with the detail. I only have files property and no extraFiles.